# separate a column but adding new rows not columns

Tags: r, bind, tidyr

I need to separate one column but not into multiple columns rather than I need new rows with duplicate values.

Some data

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- tibble(V1=1:6, V2=c(paste(letters[1:5], letters[6:10], sep=", "), "g"))
d
# A tibble: 6 × 2
     V1    V2
  <int> <chr>
1     1  a, f
2     2  b, g
3     3  c, h
4     4  d, i
5     5  e, j
6     6     g
```

Separating `V2` into new columns is straightforward using tidyr.

```
d  %>% separate(V2, c("V3", "V4"), ",")
```

But in the end I want something like this.

```
V1   V2
1     a     
1     f
2     b   
2     g
3     c
3     h
4     d
4     i
5     e
5     j
6     g
```

Tried to join in the end or to bind the rows using this code but without success:

```
d  %>% separate(V2, c("V3", "V4"), ",") %>% 
       select(1,2) %>% bind_rows(select(1,3))
```

Comment: `?tidyr::separate_rows`?

Comment: Oh......thanks a lot! Checked all functions in the related dplyr/tidyr packages but I failed to see, repeatingly.